# The method db_putHex does not exsist/is not availabe

Tags: go-ethereum

I am starting geth like the below command

```
geth --testnet --rpc --rpccorsdomain http://localhost:8089
```

and get the error `db_putHex does not exist/is not available` on this line:

```
web3.db.putHex(db, key, value);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start Geth with the appropriate RPC APIs (as well as the flags you're already passing).

`--rpcapi "db"`

Though you'll probably also want others, for example:

`--rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3"`

**Edit:**

It's also worth noting that for [`db_putHex()`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#db_puthex):

> Note this function is deprecated and will be removed in the future.

So perhaps don't rely on it too much.

Comment: I tried to run Geth with:geth --testnet --rpc --rpccorsdomain http://localhost:8089 --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3", But the error still appears

Comment: Do any of the DB commands work? It could be that it's already been deprecated/removed, but the documentation hasn't been updated...

Comment: I see that I have  a problem with the connection to the DB ,I'll check it out... thanks for the help!